# Eclipse - cannot download version 3.6.1

Tags: linux, eclipse, 32-bit

I need to download an old version of Eclipse on Linux 32bit (Eclipse version: 3.6.1).
But I face a problem with downloading - all mirrors are unavailable (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.1-201009090800/eclipse-SDK-3.6.1-linux-gtk.tar.gz)

Do anyone knows another way to download it?

**Inb4 "try to use other/new version" - I cannot. The project needs to be configured on Eclipse 3.6.1, Linux 32bit. It is impossible to use other or the new one.**

Thanks!

Comment: The [Eclipse Project Archive](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) has all the releases (but this is just the core Eclipse code).

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse "Classic" version is not available (or almost, I cannot found it) but checking on releases page (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr1) you can download all the rest versions:

- [Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR1/eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz)
- [Java](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR1/eclipse-java-helios-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz)
- [C/C++](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR1/eclipse-cpp-helios-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz)
- ...

It could be helpful for you, I think.